# .net core model binding to a Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a model as below

```
public class PeopleRequest
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public DateTime DOB {get; set;}
 public IEnumerable<string> Titles { get; set;} 
}
```

I have this API method in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPeople(PeopleRequest request)
{}
```

And my Model binding class :

```
public class RequestModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{

   public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (!context.Metadata.IsComplexType)
        {
            // Look for scrubber attributes
            var propName = context.Metadata.PropertyName;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propName))
            {
                var propInfo = context.Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(propName);
                return new SimpleTypeModelBinder(context.Metadata.ModelType);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var propName = context.Metadata.PropertyName;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propName))
            {
                var propInfo = context.Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(propName);
                var isIEnumerableFormFiles = context.Metadata.ModelType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable<string>));
                return new CollectionModelBinder<List<string>>(new SimpleTypeModelBinder(typeof(string)));

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now my question :

When I call this method with uri like this :

http://localhost:2209/api/person/complex/request?request.Name=JOE&request.DOB=03-15-2017&request.titles[0]=Dr

Breakpoint hits my api method after binding. But the Titles collection is empty without any items in it. But it is not null. What I am missing??

ANd Yes, I have added below piece of code in Startup.cs to register my ModelBinderProvider.

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new RequestModelBinderProvider());
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the default model binder bind it for you if you change your property to: `public List<string> Titles` ?

Comment: Not sure!! Never tried that. I shall verfy that

Comment: Yes. It automatically bound the data.. Not sure why I was messing up with bindings. Thanks a ton